# Is there any easy way to use a Future (which performs an http connection) inside a stateful widget without having it reconnect on every screen build?

Tags: flutter

Every time the screen is rebuilt the `getJSONfromTheSite` seems to get invoked.  Is seems because the future is placed inside the Widget build that every time I rebuild the screen it's just calling the `apiResponse.getJSONfromTheSite('sitelist')` future.  But When I try to simply move the `apiResponse.getJSONfromTheSite('sitelist')` call outside the Widget and into the initState it doesn't work at all.

I'm not fully grasping the interplay of Futures in relation to a stateful widget, but in this case I need to keep the widget stateful because Im using a pull to refresh function to rebuild my state

```
class _SitelistScreenState extends State<SitelistScreen> {
  RemoteDataSource _apiResponse = RemoteDataSource();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _apiResponse.getJSONfromTheSite('sitelist'),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Result> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data is SuccessState) {
            AppData sitelistCollection = (snapshot.data as SuccessState).value;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
//  (Do some UI stuff)
```

```
class RemoteDataSource {
  //Creating Singleton
  RemoteDataSource._privateConstructor();
  static final RemoteDataSource _apiResponse =
      RemoteDataSource._privateConstructor();

  factory RemoteDataSource() => _apiResponse;

  MyClient client = MyClient(Client());

  void init() {}

  Future<Result> getJSONfromTheSite(String call, {counter = 0}) async {
    debugPrint('Network Attempt by getJSONfromTheSite');
    try {
      final response = await client
          .request(requestType: RequestType.GET, path: call)
          .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 8));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return Result<AppData>.success(AppData.fromRawJson(response.body));
      } else {
        return Result.error(
            title: "Error", msg: "Status code not 200", errorcode: 1);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (counter < 3) {
        counter += 1;
        await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
        return getJSONfromTheSite(call, counter: counter);
      } else {
        return Result.error(
            title: "No connection", msg: "Status code not 200", errorcode: 0);
      }
    }
  }

  void dispose() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `FutureBuilder`, as the name suggests, wants to build you something using a FUTURE value that you provide. For that to happen, you should perform an operation outside the build method (for example, in the State class or in the initState function) and store its `Future` value (like a promise in javascript), to be used later on the `FutureBuilder`.

You have access to this value inside the `FutureBuilder` on the `snapshot.data` variable, as I can see you already know by looking at your code. The way I coded the following solution, you should no longer have issues about multiple requests to the website each time it builds the widget UI (`getJSONfromTheSite` will only be called once and the result from this call will be available to you inside the `FutureBuilder`!)

The solution:

```
class _SitelistScreenState extends State<SitelistScreen> {
  RemoteDataSource _apiResponse = RemoteDataSource(); // I left this here because I'm not sure if you use this value anywhere else (if you don't, simply delete this line)
  // when creating the widget's state, perform the call to the site once and store the Future in a variable
  Future<Result> _apiResponseState = RemoteDataSource().getJSONfromTheSite('sitelist');

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      child: FutureBuilder<SuccessState>(
        future: _apiResponseState,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Result> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data is SuccessState) {
            AppData sitelistCollection = (snapshot.data as SuccessState).value;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Edited answer to use `Result` as the inner type of the `Future` (instead of `SuccessState`).

Comment: Thank you!  This worked great.  All I had to do was change your `Future` line to: `Future<Result> _apiResponseState = RemoteDataSource().getJSONfromTheSite('sitelist');`

Comment: You're welcome Mark, I'm glad it worked! Btw, could I request that you mark my answer as accepted and upvote it? I'm currently trying to reach 30 reputation on StackOverflow! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `FutureBuilder`'s behavior can be expected as following according to the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during State.initState, State.didUpdateWidget, or State.didChangeDependencies.
> It must not be created during the State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the FutureBuilder.
> If the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt, the asynchronous task will be restarted.

As stated above, if the future is created at the same time as the FutureBuilder, the `FutureBuilder` will rebuilt every time there's change from the parent. To avoid this change, as well as making the call from `initState`, one easy way is to use another Widget call `StreamBuilder`.

An example from your code:

```
class RemoteDataSource {

final controller = StreamController<AppData>();

void _apiResponse.getJSONfromTheSite('sitelist') {
    // ... other lines
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       // Add the parsed data to the Stream
        controller.add(AppData.fromRawJson(response.body));
    }
    // ... other lines

}
```

In your SiteListScreen:

```
class _SitelistScreenState extends State<SitelistScreen> {
  RemoteDataSource _apiResponse = RemoteDataSource();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _apiResponse.getJSONfromTheSite('sitelist');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      child: StreamBuilder<AppData>(
        stream: _apiResponse.controller.stream, // Listen to the Stream using StreamBuilder
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            AppData sitelistCollection = snapshot.data;
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

This `StreamBuilder` is a popular concept through out most of Flutter's apps nowadays (and is the basis of many Flutter's architecture), so it's a good idea to take a good look and use the best of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way you do not need to change too much coding. Like

```
class RemoteDataSource {
  Result _result;
  //Creating Singleton
  RemoteDataSource._privateConstructor();
  static final RemoteDataSource _apiResponse =
      RemoteDataSource._privateConstructor();

  factory RemoteDataSource() => _apiResponse;

  MyClient client = MyClient(Client());

  void init() {}

  Future<Result> getJSONfromTheSite(String call, {counter = 0}) async {
    debugPrint('Network Attempt by getJSONfromTheSite');
    if (_result != null) {
      return _result;
    }
    try {
      final response = await client
          .request(requestType: RequestType.GET, path: call)
          .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 8));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        _result = Result<AppData>.success(AppData.fromRawJson(response.body));
        return _result;
      } else {
        return Result.error(
            title: "Error", msg: "Status code not 200", errorcode: 1);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (counter < 3) {
        counter += 1;
        await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
        return getJSONfromTheSite(call, counter: counter);
      } else {
        return Result.error(
            title: "No connection", msg: "Status code not 200", errorcode: 0);
      }
    }
  }

  void dispose() {}
}
```

I only store the success result to `_result`, I do not sure that you want store the error result. When you rebuild the widget, it will check if it already get the success result. If true, return the stored result, it not, call api.